# xslt output with some invalid element tag names

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Can I produce the below ouput as the transform output of a xsl file.

Output needed(no top tag and the tag names start with numbers). As it is an invalid tag, I tried setting the output method to "text"

```
<134>my</134>
<114>xml</114>
<567>notgood</567>
<789>me</789>
```

input xml

```
<Root>
<a>me</a>
</Root>
```

the xsl i used, not working as numbers are not allowed as starting of tags. However we would need to get this output.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="output">
      <Root>
        <134>my</134>
        <114>xml</114>
        <567>notgood</567>
        <789>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Root/a"/>
        </789>
      </Root>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$output/Root" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple modification** (change `<` to `&lt;`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output">
            <Root>
                &lt;134>my&lt;134>
                &lt;114>xml&lt;114>
                &lt;567>notgood&lt;567>
                &lt;789><xsl:value-of select="/Root/a"/>&lt;789>
            </Root>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$output" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root>
    <a>me</a>
</Root>
```

**the transformation produces the wanted result**:

```
            <134>my<134>
            <114>xml<114>
            <567>notgood<567>
            <789>me<789>
```

**XSLT *can* be used effectively and quite conveniently to produce non-XML output -- be it HTML or just plain text**.

Answer (score 1):

You can create text nodes with markup characters e.g.

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text><![CDATA[<789>]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="/Root/a"/>
  <xsl:text><![CDATA[</789>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

but I am not sure XSLT or any other XML tool is a good choice to create something that is not XML.

Comment: XSLT *can* be used effectively and quite conveniently to produce non-XML output -- be it HTML or just plain text

Answer (score 0):

Another option, since you are producing an output format that bears some resemblance to XML, would be to produce valid XML output and then post-process it. For example you could output `<_123>` in place of `<123>` and then get rid of the underscores using sed or similar.